# Good color to get attention in presentation

Tags: color, presentation-design

I am working on an important presentation and and need a color to highlight otherwise black text on white background (beamer presentation).

An example is highlighting data in a table with a color for one slide then letting it go back to normal.

I tried green from:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips but it stands out too much. Other colors look better but I am afraid they are not easily visible.

What colors are a good trade off for white background. Gets attention but are not too distracting (and "ugly")?

Comment: The answer is 'almost any color' will work. But to keep it simple: use red. The traditional '3 powerhouse' colors in type and design have always been black, white and red.

Answer (score 1):

As DA01 pointed out black, white and red are the historical model of choice. I prefer a sturdy orange and some nice greys where subtly is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to DA01's answer that not just any color, but any 'dark' color would fit into a white background nicely.

And, if you ever need a second color or more, there is this "color wheel" concept that guides users on the compatibility of colors when used together. I like this guide here:

http://www.worqx.com/color/color_wheel.htm